# Docker CLI command for listing image versions

Tags: docker

Is there any docker CLI command that will show me all info about image in public registry (including available image versions)? I'd love to check once in a while if my latest images are truly latest. As for now, i've discovered only search command which doesn't provide such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the answer to your question is **no**.
If you really must you can probably write a script which will do this check for you. Such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423515/how-to-automatically-update-your-docker-containers-if-base-images-are-updated).